# Android Things Wear in Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: pi-2, android, android-things

Can I install *Android Things Wear OS* in *Raspberry Pi Zero*?
if not, what will be the microprocessor I can use?

Comment: Technically, sure you can build Android for any ARM system with a decent CPU and RAM. Practically speaking, you're limited to builds aimed at RPi, and Android Things isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I install *Android Things Wear OS* in *Raspberry Pi Zero*?

*Android Things Wear OS* does not exist. There is [Android Things OS](https://developer.android.com/things/get-started) which does not support *Raspberry Pi Zero* (see the [list of supported hardware](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware)).